# How to Scrape Td from Text inside a Container with Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape text from within a container, but I can't manage to figure out how to scrape some of it.

This code is for a scraper that is pulling three columns for each entry from a webpage formatted as follows:

```
<td class="EP">1</td>
</tr>
<tr class="EG">
<td>
</td>
<td>
<a href="https://www.COMPANYWEBSITE/">COMPANY NAME</a>
</td>
<td DO="9999">
<div class="BN">9999</div>
<img src="https://www.IMAGE.com">
</td>
<td>
Keyword 1, Keyword 2, Keyword 3, Keyword 4
</td>
<td>New York City</td>
<td>USA</td>
```

I've successfully scraped the COMPANY NAME and BN (i.e., 9999), but I need to scrape each of the keywords as well, and that's where I'm having trouble.

I've used the following Python code:

```
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser") 
TT = page_soup.findAll("tr",{"class":"EG"})
container = TT[0]

for container in TT:

    company_name = container.a.text

    b_n = container.div.text

    keywords = container.?????
```

I'm stuck on how to get the keywords into my output. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use nth-of-type

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<td class="EP">1</td>
</tr>
<tr class="EG">
<td>
</td>
<td>
<a href="https://www.COMPANYWEBSITE/">COMPANY NAME</a>
</td>
<td DO="9999">
<div class="BN">9999</div>
<img src="https://www.IMAGE.com">
</td>
<td>
Keyword 1, Keyword 2, Keyword 3, Keyword 4
</td>
<td>New York City</td>
<td>USA</td>

'''

page_soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
TT = page_soup.findAll("tr",{"class":"EG"})
for container in TT:
    print(container.select_one('td:nth-of-type(4)').text)
```

Comment: Great! This worked better for me because it didn't kick back a "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str"

Answer (score 0):

As long as the keywords are always in the fourth column, you can select all `TD`s from the container and choose the fourth one:

```
container.findAll('td')[3].string.strip().split(', ')
#['Keyword 1', 'Keyword 2', 'Keyword 3', 'Keyword 4']
```

Comment: That seems to work! Although now I have brackets around the entire output.

Comment: Now when I try to write to .csv, I get "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str"

Comment: A CSV writer has function writerow(), use it.